# Bash: Set a process to die in start parameters with sighup

Tags: bash

Is it possible to set a process to die in its start parameters?

What I'm trying to do is set a process to die either before it's started or when it's starting.

When I try to get a pid of an opened named  pipe with `cat > $pipe` by adding an ampersand and $! after it, it spams the terminal with ">" symbols, so I was wondering if it were possible to start `cat > $pipe` with a parameter to die on a PID's SIGHUP.

How would I go about doing this? If I put anything *after* the `cat > $pipe`, it will not work correctly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"get a pid of an opened named pipe"*
A named pipe does not have a pid, only processes have pids (the clue is in the 'p')

However, that does not appear to be anything to do with the title of the question.  By default, a process will die on a SIGHUP.  However, a child process inherits the parent's signal mask, so if the parent ignored SIGHUP then that will be the case in the child (not true for handlers).  So you can force a die with (for example):

```
trap 'exit 128' SIGHUP
```

But how does that part of the question relate to named pipes?  Are you trying to find which processes have the pipe open?  You can iterate through /proc for that.

EDIT after comments from the OP:

If you run `cat > mypipe &` then the `cat` will hang trying to access the keyboard - `cat` by default reads STDIN.

```
[1]+  Stopped                 cat > mypipe
```

So then you have to bring it into forground (`fg`) to enter data, normally terminated by `<CTRL>+D`.  I am at a loss as to why you want to use `cat` in this way.

Anyway, if you run in background it is very easy to get a background job's pid:
assuming it is job number 1

```
set $(jobs -l %1)
pid=$2
```

Maybe you could further investigate why you can't run the job in background, and show an example (use the `script` command to get a copy of your session in a file called `typescript`)

Comment: If you don't put the job into background, then the parent process will wait unil the `cat` has finished (then, of course, it no longer has a pid).  The "spam" of `>` is probably the continuation prompt.  Could we see an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in parentheses? `(cat > $pipe) &$`

Comment: That backgrounds the process, which I'd like to get the PID of the process without backgrounding it.